# convert all non string JSON values into string values

Tags: python, json

In python I have JSON in which all the values have to be changed to string. The values may be a number, boolean, null or anything.

```
{
  "obj1": [
    {
      "n1": "n",
      "n2": 1,
      "n3": true
    },
    {
      "n1": "n",
      "n2": 1,
      "n3": null
    }
  ]
}
```

The expected result is all the values should be formatted as a string.

Example:

```
{
  "obj1": [
    {
      "n1": "n",
      "n2": "1",
      "n3": "true"
    },
    {
      "n1": "n",
      "n2": "1",
      "n3": "null"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you !!!

Comment: Why not iterate your objects and `str()` the values?

Comment: I added an answer here, please let me know if this solves your issue? Otherwise add some information and I will see if I can help.

Comment: Yes that helps a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for you here. The following script will take a JSON object in the format that you have specified, iterate through it and create a new json object where non-string values are converted to strings with `json.dumps`.

This scripts takes a JSON object - if you are starting out with a string - then you will need to convert it to an object with `json.loads(myString);`

```py
import json;

myJSONObj = {"obj1": [{"n1": "n", "n2": 1, "n3": True}, {"n1": "n", "n2": 1, "n3": None}]};

newJSON = {};

for obj in myJSONObj:
    newJSON[obj] = [];
    for item in myJSONObj[obj]:
        newJSONArrayObj = {};
        for key, value in item.items():
            if not isinstance(value, str):
                newJSONArrayObj[key] = json.dumps(value);
            else:
                newJSONArrayObj[key] = value;
        newJSON[obj].append(newJSONArrayObj);

newJSONString = json.dumps(newJSON);
print(newJSONString);
```

Here's the same code with comments:

```
import json;

# assigning the source json object
myJSONObj = {"obj1": [{"n1": "n", "n2": 1, "n3": True}, {"n1": "n", "n2": 1, "n3": None}]};

# creating a new target json object, empty
newJSON = {};

# enter the obj1 object
for obj in myJSONObj:
    # create the key from the existing obj1 object, and assign an empty array
    newJSON[obj] = [];
    # loop through all the array items in the source obj1 array
    for item in myJSONObj[obj]:
        # for each, create a new empty json object
        newJSONArrayObj = {};
        # for each of the key-value pairs in the object in the array
        for key, value in item.items():
            # in case that the value is not a string, dump it to the new object as a string with its original key
            if not isinstance(value, str):
                newJSONArrayObj[key] = json.dumps(value);
            # otherwise, just assign the string to the key in the new object
            else:
                newJSONArrayObj[key] = value;
        # finally push the new object into the array
        newJSON[obj].append(newJSONArrayObj);

# converting the new JSON object to a string and printing it
newJSONString = json.dumps(newJSON);
print(newJSONString);
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Any full solution should use recursion